# How to disable login screen appearance on client machine (Windows 7 Ult) with GPO (Win Server 2008 R2)

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

How to disable login screen to appear on client computers (Windows 7 U) with GPO in windows server 2008 R2? 
I want that when i turn user32 machine ON it should logs on directly without a username/password prompt/screen.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean so that the client computer automatically logs on.

In which case, this is what you want. But be warned, it brings a security risk.

[How to configure auto-logon in Active Directory](https://serverfault.com/questions/441263/how-to-configure-auto-logon-in-active-directory)

Comment: Thank you Paul! i will check it later and tell you if that worked.